# Facebook - og:type reading issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I have some troubles with facebook comments. Post doesn't appears on facebook's wall when I leave a comment and check "Also post on facebook". This is a demo page I play with `websendbox.16mb.com/page22.html`.

**Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger** detect this error:

"The '`og:type`' property is required, but not present." but this property exists.

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just rescraped the page with the debugger and the error was gone: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

If OG tags don´t work, just hit the debugger and refresh the URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. But problem is that the page with comments plugin will have dynamic URL (websendbox.16mb.com/page22.html is sendbox demo only). Does it means rescrapping the page everytime i added new a page?

Comment: that will not work. open graph tags are not meant to be used for dynamic stuff. sooner or later the title will get locked and you can´t change it even with the debugger. so that exact same url should only have one static set of open graph tags.

Comment: ok. thnx. but i still misunderstood one thing: posts checked for submitting on facebook wall not appears there till i scrap this (new created) page at least ones. 
so i think scrapping it's neccessary condition for clear fb-comments working. is it so?

Comment: it takes a while for facebook to recognize the tags afaik, so the first time it may not work correctly, yes.